# Facebook share scraper doesn't register al: tags

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a website that I use to return Facebook og: and al: tags for my app sharing links. All my links are intended to be opened in the mobile app. It works fine everywhere, besides Facebook/Messenger, half of the time links are opened in their built-in browser

I used their debugger tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

And I get zero warnings or errors. As I understood from their documentation, in order to tell Facebook to open my app links in my app directly, I need to return al: type meta tags, including package name, bundle id's, url's etc. Without these tags, it just opens their built-in browser

I successfully return all this data in my page's head tag. And even Facebook share debugger successfully fetches all of these. But it does not register them, which means that my app links are still opened in their browser. Only *og:title*, *og:description* and *og:image* are registered

I can see my *al:* tags when I click **Show All Raw Tags**, but they do not appear in **Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties**. I can press **Debug** button for numerous times, they won't appear until I click **Scrape again**, only then they do appear for this link and my mobile apps are opened. And the same for every of my shared app links.

I have no clue about what could cause this

Here's an [example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fshenanny.se%2Fnanny%2Fff34878e99f5d53e96aebf5ee35b4f55b3fd4f7c) of my app link

Comment: Post your code example. It would help to see the full <head> section

Comment: @HackSlash here it is https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fshenanny.se%2Fnanny%2Fff34878e99f5d53e96aebf5ee35b4f55b3fd4f7c

Comment: No. I meant: Post your code in your question so that people can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You need different tag for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone:

iOS:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
```

Android:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="example://applinks" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Example App" />
```

Windows:

```
<meta property="al:windows_phone:url" content="example://applinks" />
<meta property="al:windows_phone:app_name" content="Example App" />
```

SOURCE REFERENCE:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/navigation-protocol

Comment: All are present, besides Windows ones